# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).uploadify is not a function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I got the error when I try to upload pic.
I can't figure it out why I this keeps giving Me an issue.

[There I downloaded this script](https://github.com/RonnieSan/uploadify)

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).uploadify is not a function

[image: Eror]

My View:

```
@model CRM.DataModel.Entities.Dictionary.TrainingType
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Edit"; }

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="@Model.Id" name="Id">

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputCarName" class="form-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputCarName" value="@Model.Name" name="Name">
    </div>

    <div>
        Click Select files to upload files.
        <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
    </div>
    <div id="uploaded"></div>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/UploadifyContent/jquery.uploadify.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/UploadifyContent/jquery.uploadify.min.js")"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/UploadifyContent/uploadify.css")" />
}
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'swf': "@Url.Content("~/Content/UploadifyContent/uploadify.swf")",
            'cancelImg': "@Url.Content("~/Content/UploadifyContent/uploadify-cancel.png")",
            'uploader': "@Url.Action("Upload", "TrainingType")",
            'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
                $("#uploaded").append("<img src='" + data + "' alt='Uploaded Image' />");
            }
        });
        });

    </script>
}
```

I have to update My ask and show it:
[image: some error]

[image: error1]
[image: error2]

Comment: Not related to the actual question, but relying on the filename extension when checking the type of the file is a suicide.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot add other pics. But I'm sure this's issue actually related  if We fix it others is gone

Comment: The issue I mentioned is built in the library, the library itself needs to  be fixed.

Comment: I fix it.  Thank you Sir. you were right two last issues because library was not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load script tags in following order to solve this problem

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.uploadify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Since plugin is a extension of jquery, load jQuery first and then load plugin it should solve the issue.

Refer : https://github.com/RonnieSan/uploadify/blob/master/index.php

Comment: Thank you Sir. I did it and I have one issue `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).uploadify is not a function` other solved.

Comment: Can you share what you are getting when you type $ or jQuery in browser console. I am damn sure jquery is not loaded properly.  Can you confirm jquery loaded to browser

Comment: My _layout has ` @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` . I'm sure library Jquery is loaded

Comment: Screenshots are confusing
One says jquery not defined - to solve load jquery first.
If you are sure about jquery is loaded - Try with same version of jquery used just for testing